# Find Dimension of $[\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q]=?$

Tags: field-theory

$\beta$ is the root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-14x^3+49x-21$.

(1)Then Dimension of $[\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q]=?$

(2)Describe the element of $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ in term of $\beta$

My try:(1)By Eisenstein's criteria $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$ then Dimension of $[\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q]=4$

(2)$\mathbb Q(\beta)=\{a_0+a_1\beta+a_2\beta^2+a_3\beta^3:a_i\in\mathbb Q\}$

please check.Thank you

Comment: Last time I checked there were infinitely many elements in $\Bbb{Q}$, so I remove the [tag:finite-fields] tag :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me.

**Nit-picking:**

You should specify that you  are using the prime $7$ when using Eisenstein's criterion.

As I read (2) (although I may have misunderstood), you're asked to describe not the entire $\Bbb Q(\beta)$, but an arbitrary element of $\Bbb Q(\beta)$. That means that the correct answer is "$a_0+a_1\beta+a_2\beta^2 + a_3\beta^3$ where $a_i\in\Bbb Q$", without the $\{\hphantom{{}\cdot{}}\}$.

$[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q]$ is a natural number, not a space with dimension. So it's not that the dimension of $[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q]$ is $4$, it's that $[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q]$ *itself* is $4$.

I'm sure there are other little details as well, but they're not all that important. You seem to have understood everything the exercise was meant to train you in, and that is what's important.